# Questions to find minimum features that is required to train a model

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, machine-learning

I have a dataframe which contains price_range(target_attribute) and other features columns. I have a question that asks me to find the smallest subset of the possible features(smallest number of features columns) such that the score of the model is over 0.4

Right now, my idea is that drop the feature columns one by one to see when the score of model is closest to 0.4. Is that right? How do I drop column one by one in dataframe?

Comment: I wouldn't go with this approach. Think about the case where you drop a high importance feature, you might end up with a lot of remaining features to achieve the score you want. Remember, you are looking for having the smallest subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of ML model are you using? Tree-based models (like Gradient Boosting and Random Forests) have a "Feature Importance" measurement that can be used to do so. You can fit your model with every feature, check `clf.feature_importances_` and try removing the ones with lower scores.

You can check the documentation here: [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel)

Another option is to follow what @Matt said, and use something like Recursive Feature Elimination [Here is a simple example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_rfe_digits.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-rfe-digits-py):

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
rfe = RFE(estimator=svc, n_features_to_select=1, step=1)
rfe.fit(X, y)
ranking = rfe.ranking_
```

A final, simpler approach, is to remove features with a too low variance. The intuition here is that, usually, features with a low variance won't do much to help your model discriminate between classes. You must set a threshold for how high the variance should be in order to be kept in the dataset. [This](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#removing-features-with-low-variance) is how you do it with sklearn:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold
X = [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
sel = VarianceThreshold(threshold=(.8 * (1 - .8)))
sel.fit_transform(X)
```

Note that these examples came from the sklearn [tutorial](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html) on feature selection.

Comment: Good to know! If this solved your problem, please mark this answer as the right answer, by clicking on the checkmark on the left.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Recursive feature elimination. What this will do is fit a model and remove the least important feature (or features depending on the step size you set) until it reaches the desired number of features.

See [here](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/features/rfecv.html) and [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html)